# help with gravity gun mechanism

Tags: unity, c#

```
public void HitWithRay()
{
    Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
    {
        RaycastHit2D hit2d = Physics2D.Raycast(player.playerbulletFirePoint.position, mousePos , 10f);
        if (hit2d.collider == null)
            return;
        else
        {
            Vector2 velocityDirX = this.transform.position - hit2d.transform.position;
            hit2d.rigidbody.AddForce (velocityDirX * pullingForce);
        }  
        Debug.Log(hit2d.transform.gameObject.tag);
    }
        Debug.DrawRay(player.playerbulletFirePoint.position, mousePos , Color.white);
}
```

**This script was actually grabbing the objects and hitting the player
the help I wanted here is I want to stop the grabbed object in front of player**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest adding an OnTrigger to detect if the object is in contact with the player, and then set object velocity to zero so the object stop moving.
You can do:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
        if(other.CompareTag("Object")){
            Rigidbody2D rigidbody2D=other.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            rigidbody2D.velocity=new Vector2(0,0);
            
        }
    }
```

If you need the object to stop at some distance from player, you can use:

```
GameObject object;
object = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(player.position, radius, objectLayer); 
       Rigidbody2D rigidbody2D=object.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            rigidbody2D.velocity=new Vector2(0,0);
```